# How to ignore BP1.1 compliance errors using wsimport?

Tags: java, wsdl, wsimport

I'm trying to import a WSDL using `wsimport` (JDK 6).

This fails, however, telling me to:

> turn off BP 1.1 conformance warnings

How can I configure these in `wsimport`?

I've tried running wsimport using:

```
wsimport http://tripauthority.com/hotel.asmx?WSDL
```

But it only replies:

> its not WS-I BP 1.1 compliant: the wsdl binding has mixed style, it must be rpc-literal or document-literal operation. try running wsimport with -extension switch.

And I've tried adding the flag `-extension` but wsimport still won't complete (maybe I'm doing it wrong?):

```
wsimport http://tripauthority.com/hotel.asmx?WSDL -extension
```

Can anyone help?  Thanks

P.s. I can't use Eclipse's Wizard for creating web clients using a WSDL, since this will run on Google App Engine which doesn't allow the `rmi` package.  Unless there's a way to tell this Wizard not to use RMI, which I'd also be interested in.

**Update**

The supplier additionally recommends this, but again, I don't know what needs to be done for this:

> Recommendation: To make it conformant change the implementation of the
>   service to use 'rpc-literal' or 'document-literal' SOAP messages. You
>   need to add explicit Use=SoapBindingUse.Literal property to all
>   service and method level attributes: SoapRpcService, SoapRpcMethod,
>   SoapDocumentService, SoapDocumentMethod.
>
> Recommendation: To make binding conformant add explicit SoapRpcMethod
>   or SoapDocumentMethod attribute to all WebMethods of this binding.

Comment: Can you please post the listing of the WSDL? Or a link if it's too long?

Comment: @Tudor I added the link to the real WSDL in the post.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You could download the WSDL to your local disk and from the binding elements remove the operations whose names are "SubmitRequestRpc". Then try wsimport with the local modified file.

Comment: Ok I'll try it.  But will removing those operations have any other repercussions?

Comment: If you're not calling the service with those operations, then there should not be any problem. The problem is that they are rpc-encoded, which is not supported by BP 1.1

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't look like it'll work for me.  Is there a way to fix this by specifying a binding?

Comment: Are you getting an error or what is happening?

Comment: I take it back.  It compiled, but I'm a little wary about not having those methods in there... are you sure that'll work?  If you can describe what that is doing, I'll mark your answer as 'accepted'

Comment: Simply put, you are removing the operations that are not BP 1.1 compliant. Since you're not using them anyway, it's ok to delete them.

Comment: @Tudor thanks again for all your help.  If you submit anything as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the WSDL to your local disk and from the binding elements remove the operations whose names are "SubmitRequestRpc", if you're not using them. Then try wsimport with the local modified file.

Comment: and what if we need them how do we solve this issue, i have thesam problem with my wsdl